# Cannot index existing data from mongo to elastic using mongoose

Tags: node.js, elasticsearch, mongoose, mongoose-schema, mongoosastic

I'm trying to index data from mongo DB to elasticsearch using mongoose, my documents are already existing
 or maybe there is a way to indexing all data automatically without a schema
please help me!

**This is my document:**

[image]

**This is my node code:**

```
const mongoose     = require('mongoose');
const mongoosastic = require('mongoosastic');

mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost:27017/landingZoneDB');


var commentsSchema=new mongoose.Schema({
    joined_date:{type:String} ,
 comment_date:{type:String}, 
    comment_body:{type:String},user_link:{type:String} ,
    posts_count:{type:String}, user_name:{type:String}});


var DNMAvengers_tbSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    crawl_date:{type:String}
    , views:{type:String}
    , replies:{type:String}
    ,title:{type: String}
    ,comments: [commentsSchema] 
    ,link:{type: String}
    ,forum_title:{type: String}
    ,avatar_details: {avatar_name:{type: String} ,avatar_pass:{type: String}, avatar_user:{type:String}, avatar_email:{type: String} }
});

var comments = mongoose.model('comments', commentsSchema);


DNMAvengers_tbSchema.plugin(mongoosastic);

var DNMAvengers_tb = mongoose.model('DNMAvengers_tb', DNMAvengers_tbSchema)
  , stream = DNMAvengers_tb.synchronize()
  , count = 0;

var stream = DNMAvengers_tb.synchronize({}, {saveOnSynchronize: true})

stream.on('data', function(err, doc){
  count++;
});
stream.on('close', function(){
  console.log('indexed ' + count + ' documents!');
});

stream.on('error', function(err){
  console.log(err);
});
```

**That my result:**

C:\Users\Administrator>node RUN.js
(node:2816) DeprecationWarning: current URL string parser is deprecated, and will be removed in a future version. To use the new parser, pass option { useNewUrlParser: true } to MongoClient.connect.
(node:2816) DeprecationWarning: current Server Discovery and Monitoring engine is deprecated, and will be removed in a future version. To use the new Server Discover and Monitoring engine, pass option { useUnifiedTopology: true } to the MongoClient constructor.
indexed 0 documents!

Comment: you need to jest call create mapping before you synchronizing existing document
Add this to 
    DNMAvengers_tb.createMapping({
    },function(err, mapping){
      
    });

Comment: thanks, it helps but now it syncs in the first time and if I add new data to my mongo DB it is don't sync it to the elastic search, I get this error ** Error [ERR_UNHANDLED_ERROR]: Unhandled error. (null)**
I don't want always to delete my elastic search data and to sync again.
how can I sync the different??